# wordpress excerpt special character (Vietnamese)?

Tags: wordpress

my code in wordpress

```
<?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 160); ?>
```

but in view: `thiên nhiên tuyệt vời, nh��...`

How to fix special character

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mb_substr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) instead

Comment: i'm use `function get_excerpt($count){
  $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
  $excerpt = get_the_content();
  $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
  $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $count);
  $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
  return $excerpt;
}` `<?php echo get_excerpt(168); ?>` and done! Thanks